# Maslov canonical operator

Tags: asymptotics, linear-pde, quantum-mechanics, hyperbolic-pde

Suppose $\Lambda$ is a Lagrangian submainfold of $M=T^*\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $x_i$ be the standard coordinate on the base manifold $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\eta_j$ the coordinate on the dual. According to a lemma of Arnol'd, for any given point $p$ on $\Lambda$, there is a neighborhood $U_p$ of it that projects diffeomorphically onto an open set of one of the Lagrangian planes $\{x^{(1)}=0,\eta^{(2)}=0\}$ where $x^{(1)}$ and $\eta^{(2)}$ are subsets of $\{x_i\}$ and $\{\eta_j\}$.

The pre-canonical Maslov operator on $U_p$ is the operator $K$ that maps $\varphi\in C_0^\infty(U_p)$ to a function on $\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^+$ $$K_{U_p}\varphi= u(x,\hbar)=(-\frac{\hbar}{2\pi i})^k\int J(x^{(2)},\eta^{(1)})\exp[i\hbar (S(x^{(2)},\eta^{(1)})+x^{(2)}\cdot \eta^{(2)})]\varphi(r(x^{(2)},\eta^{(1)}))d\eta^{(1)} $$ where $k$ is the number of elements in $\eta^{(1)}$, $J$ is a Jacobian factor, $S$ is the generating function, and $r$ is the inverse of the projection of $U_p$ to $\{x^{(1)}=0,\eta^{(2)}=0\}$.

The idea of the operator is of course to take a partial Fourier transform. However, the functions in question $S$, $J$ and $\varphi$ are only defined on $U_p$, and pulls back to a function defined only on an open subset of $\eta^{(1)}$. How can we take the partial Fourier transform of such functions?